# String Rearrangment C++

Tags: c++, string, function, stringstream

Im pulling a text file - it will be input by user
currently its just pulling from C:\Dump\test.txt
I want to re-arrange the words in said file

This is what i have so far

```
static string revFunc(string a)
{
    ifstream inp;
    inp.open(a, std::ios::in);
    string lines;

    while(getline(inp, lines)){
        istringstream iss(lines);
        string outstr;
        string word;
        iss >> outstr;
        if (inp >> word){
            outstr = word + ' ' + outstr + ' ';
            cout << outstr;

        }
    }return 0;
}
```

the string a is the path to file on the hdd
this will parse 2 lines backwards 
there are ~13 lines in the tester file

this is from int main()

```
int main(){
string file;
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
int choice;

system("cls");

cout << "Enter Filename: " << endl;
file = "C:\\Dump\\test.txt";
cout << file;
//cin >> file;

cout <<"MENU"<<endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "1. Count Words" << endl;
cout << "2. Count Lines" << endl;
cout << "3. Index Words" << endl;
cout << "4. Average Length of Words" << endl;
cout << "5. Print Text File to Screen" << endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "??: ";
cin >> choice;

switch(choice){

case 1: cout << "Words: " << wordFunc(file) << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
case 2: cout << "Lines: " << lineFunc(file, lines) << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
case 3: indexFunc(file);
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
case 4: cout << "Average Length: " << avgWordFunc(file) << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
case 5: printStrFunc(file);
        cout <<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
case 6: revFunc(file);
        cout << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        break;

}

return 0;
}
```

Then the program aborts - im sure due to bad coding :) 
Any help pointing out my ridiculous mistakes are appreciated

Comment: Could you post the complete code? Try to make it minimal - http://sscce.org

Comment: What is `return 0` at end of `revFunc()` ?

Comment: You don't return a valid string.

Comment: I had return outstr; inside the if loop but it would only return one line of reversed string and quit - thus i put return 0; there for, well i guess no reason, other than having something to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your `refFunc` returns a `string`, but the return value is `0` (an `int`, not a `string`).

This will result in a problem as the program tries to use a string object, and finds "garbage" (that has been allocated in anticipation of a string but has not been filled with the correct bits of a string).

To fix, you either need to change the return *type* to `int` or change the return *value* to a valid string (e.g. `""`).

Alternatively, if you are not using the return value (as is the case in your example), you can change the return type to `void`.  In this case, use only `return;` (note: no value after return), or you can leave the whole return statement out;

NOTE: To prevent from future such mistakes, configure your compiler to compile with maximum warnings setting and possibly with warnings turned into errors.  This will prevent you from compiling your program without at least the compiler telling you you are doing something (most likely) incorrectly

NOTE: Do not learn the habit of using `system()` even for pausing your application.  It is platform dependent, and can introduce a security risk (although I don't think you will worry about that for a while)

Comment: UGH - i hate making stupid mistakes like that - i changed to return ""; no longer kicks an error but still only gives out 2 lines reversed

Comment: Maybe only two lines have at least 2 words in them?

Comment: Nah - they all have more than 2 in them - most have over 5 or so
I changed the if loop to a while loop and it printed out all of the words re arranged (about 100 times ha)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `return 0` and replace it by a valid `string`

I think you should use `return outstr;` at the end of the `revFunc` function, instead of `return 0;`

Also, move `string outstr;` at top of `while(...)` :

```
static string revFunc(string a)
{
    ifstream inp;
    inp.open(a, std::ios::in);
    string lines;

    string outstr;
    while(getline(inp, lines)){
        istringstream iss(lines);
        string word;
        iss >> outstr;
        if (inp >> word){
            outstr = word + ' ' + outstr + ' ';
            cout << outstr;

        }
    }return outstr;
}
```

Comment: i changed to return outstr; = undeclaired identifier

Comment: moved inside the while loop and only gives 2 words reversed

Comment: OK, that's your problem right there: if you move the return in the while, you are exiting from the while after the first iteration.  (See Masoud's edits on how to fix if you want to go with their sugestion)

Comment: this worked as well as return ""; - theres somthing wrong with the way im pulling strings in i believe 

the words im getting that are rearranged are peppered throughout the document - o well -thanks a TON guys! Ill figure it out from there lol